# UIPageControl pageIndicator change location to left or right side in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

As we all know, when we use `UIPageControl` in our app, `pageIndicator` displayed at the bottom of our app. Now what I want to know is, how can I move that page `pageIndicator` to left or right side of our app in swift as **vertical**?

Comment: You want it vertical?

Comment: can you show some image for that what exactly you want?

Comment: @ashmi123 as vertical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform your `PageControl` by Rotating it, and then set its origin where you want.

In swift 3.0 just change transform value like

```
PageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI / 2))
```

In swift 2.0

```
pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI / 2))
pageControl.frame.origin.x = 0
pageControl.frame.origin.y = 65
```

**OutPut**

[Before Rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdf4x.png)

[After Rotate and changing frame origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJsSD.png)